# static transformation publisher

Tags: ros, transforms, quaternion, tf2, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to do a static transformation

the actual frame is in x forward y right z up
the new frame if x forward y left and z up

I want to do transformation from the new to the actual frame using the static publish

```
<launch>

 <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser" args="0 0 0 x y z w  /uav/base_link_ENU /laser  100"/>

</launch>
```

What should I replace the x y z and w
And do I need to have a listener ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208002/static-transformation-publisher/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-04-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`x y z w` is only used if you want to specify orientation using a quaternion. If you want to use Euler angles, you can use the other parameter order. From the `static_transform_publisher`:

```
Usage: static_transform_publisher x y z yaw pitch roll frame_id child_frame_id  period (milliseconds)
```

Note the order `ypr` instead of the often used `rpy`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2015-04-28**:
Thank you  :)

**Comment by [malharjajoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33038/malharjajoo/) on 2018-04-10**:
Make sure to use radians for the yaw, pitch and roll.

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-09-15**:
@gvdhoorn Can I know what are the advantages and disadvantages of using Euler over Quaternions?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-16**:
This would be a rather broad discussion @AM97.

One of the biggest advantages of quaternions would be they don't suffer from gimbal lock and have a single unique representation and interpretation. Euler angles both suffer from gimbal lock and have at least 12 different orders of rotation (note @malharjajoo's comment about the order of rotations).

For more, I'd refer you to sites like wikipedia (for a quick overview) or the relevant (math) literature.

**Comment by [AM97](https://answers.ros.org/users/41623/am97/) on 2019-09-16**:
@gvdhoorn I understand why we are using Quaternions. But I would also like to know what are the benefits if I use Eulers?.
P.S I know to avoid Gimbal lock is one of the main reason to use Quaternions even though they are little complex. I am just curious to know what will be advantages if we use euler in robotics?

I think we can keep track of when you approach a singularity (gimbal lock). In the singularity, angles may flip instantaneously from 90 to -90 degrees but although it would be difficult in the real world.

**Comment by [Lennart](https://answers.ros.org/users/52806/lennart/) on 2020-05-19**:
The advance of Euler is: It is easier to imagine rotation around the three axes z y x, than to imagine Quaternions.